# Python in Visual Studio 2015 for Micsrosoft Windows CE 7.0

Tags: python, visual-studio-2015, windows-ce

**Questions:**
(**Q1**) How can I write a GUI Python code in Visual Studio 2015 for a hand held scanner which runs Microsoft Windows CE 7.0 - (**Q2**) how can I upload the python code from VS'15 onto the scanner's Windows CE 7.0.

**Background/Research:** I have a hand held scanner where we want to create our own GUI so that the user interface is dead simple. Some reading led that Visual Studio 2015 will be required as it supports Python. I installed it and wrote a "hello world!' code in Python within VS'15. Moving on to a GUI I will be using TKinter or a similar library that will create a GUI. But I just want to ask (**Q3**) if there is also another alternative method that I might have missed?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no official python implementation supporting Windows CE and the existing one http://pythonce.sourceforge.net/ was no longer updated since 2013.
VS2015 supports Python tools and you may even be able to do remote debugging if the python runtime supports it, but I never tried that on Windows CE.
If you need to implement a simple GUI application and your device supports it, you may use the .NET Compact Framework and develop your application in C# or VB.NET, I know they are not as nice as Python :) but it is probably the simplest solution.
That would also mean using VS2008 (developing for CE nowadays is like travelling back in time).